# Spring Boot model not updating in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using a simple spring boot application and I cannot get my column names to update in my database.  I CAN get the name of the tables to update, but I cannot get the column names to update.

Here is my User class:

```
package com.helpinghand.HelpingHand.Backend.Model;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String streetAddress;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String city;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String state;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String zip;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean isAdmin;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String streetAddress, String city, String state, String zip, String email, boolean isAdmin, LocalDateTime createDate, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.email = email;
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
        this.createdDate = createDate;
//        this.password = password;
        setPassword(password);  // Set the hashed password
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getStreetAddress() {
        return streetAddress;
    }

    public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
        isAdmin = admin;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime createDate) {
        this.createdDate = createDate;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

//    public void setPassword(String password) {
//        this.password = password;
//    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        // TODO: Perform password hashing here
        this.password = hashPassword(password);
    }

    private String hashPassword(String password) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    }
}
```

Here is my application.properties class:

```
server.port = 8080

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/helpinghand
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#server.port=8080
#
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/helpinghand
#spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

I have removed my password in the application.properities class.

I have refreshed the schema in MySQL.

I have deleted the entire schema from the database and recreated it.  I have rebuilt my maven project many times.  For some reason when the database starts up it names the columns in the format "first_name" instead of firstName.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GACBo.png)

The database also does not recognize the "not null" attributes I have on some of the variables in my User class.

It also doesn't recognize the id parameter of my model.  If I use a manual query in MySQL to enter a row into the database I have to include an id value.  Shouldn't this be auto generated?

Comment: Seems like you've don't commuting the transaction. Check your repository.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "you've don't commuting the transaction".  What should I check in my repository?

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes for your name:

```
@Column(name = "\"firstName\"", nullable = false)
private String firstName;
```

Comment: This does not seem to work.

Comment: Neither does this     @Column(name = "`firstName`", nullable = false)